# Logrotate installed, settings for nginx duplicated between two servers...but different log file sizes

Tags: nginx, logrotate

I have two web servers, using nginx, I have logrotate installed on both, and the settings for both logrotate.conf and logrotate.d/nginx are both the same.

Both store logs in /home/websitename/.pm2/logs

In the first webserver, the logs are structured:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 13:21 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_13-21-12.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 13:46 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_13-46-12.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 14:00 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_14-00-12.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 14:19 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_14-19-42.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 14:42 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_14-42-42.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 15:09 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_15-09-12.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 15:36 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_15-36-12.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 16:00 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_16-00-42.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 16:24 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_16-24-42.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 website website   11M Feb 27 16:48 example.com-out-2__2018-02-27_16-48-12.log
```

As you can see they are all a certain file size, multiples of log files per day etc...

On the second webserver the logging is just to a single large file. Located i the same /home/websitename/.pm2/logs  location.

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 website website  19G Mar  9 14:04 example.com-error-0.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 website website 7.2G Mar  7 06:09 example.com-error-1.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 website website 5.2G Mar  9 14:04 example.com-out-0.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 website website 1.2G Feb 23 23:15 example.com-out-1.log
```

I *think* the reason for the error-0 and error-1 logs, was when the server rebooted, and it started a new log.

Question is, how do I change the logging so that it creates the smaller files and not this monstrous all in one 19GB type file?

I feel like I have looked thru every setting, and can't figure it out!  I "think" logrotate is working, as I get a current day status when I check logrotate.status.

/etc/logrotate.conf:

This is the /etc/logrotate.conf file:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create
# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}
/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

/etc/logrotate.d/nginx file:

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 4
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 nginx adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f /var/run/nginx.pid ]; then
                        kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
                fi
        endscript
}
```

Comment: Can you include your logrotate configuration too?

Comment: Added conf file above

Comment: The `nginx` `logrotate` config you've shown can't be what is doing the rotation on your first server (it's not looking at the directory with your logs in and it would set different ownership on the new log files). This means that log rotation on the working server must be done by something else. Check any other files under `/etc/logrotate.d` and look at your crontab entries. However the fact that the historical files are all the same size implies that this isn't being done on a time schedule so check the logging section of your `nginx` config as well.